# ArcGIS JS API Polygon's WKID conversion with gsvc.project

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, convert, coordinate-system

I'm trying to convert polygon from wkid 3301 to wkid 4326. I've been using this code snippet for converting points, but I'm not sure how I would accomplish this to create a polygon object. I'm not even sure if gsvc.project() is the best solution. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");
var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });
mapHandler.gsvc.project([ geometry ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {
    pt = projectedPoints[0];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this with the following code:

```
mapHandler.gsvc.project([ geometry ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {
    var polygonJSON = {"rings": projectedPoints[0].rings, "spatialReference": {"wkid": projectedPoints[0].spatialReference.wkid}};
    var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(polygonJSON);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for posting the solution. You should mark this answer as accepted, so that future readers will quickly now what worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for following up and keeping the site's Q&A format working well.

Comment: You should be able create straight from the JSON. var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(projectPoints[0]);

Comment: Apparently the short version didn't work. Removed that from the answer.